# How to skip default index (series column on the left) when writing data from dataframe in pandas into Excel through xlwings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlwings

```
  item  sales
0   A    100
1   B    200
2   C    300
3   D    230
4   E    470
5   F    168
```

I have a dataset like above in pandas dataframe, and I wrote those data into an Excel file using xlwings, but I don't want to the series index column on the left (0,1,2,3,4...). How do I only import the table without a number index column?

Comment: What is the code you used to write the pandas dataframe to an Excel file?

Comment: It looks like you can use ```Range``` to specify the columns you want to read in. For example, ```xw.Range('B:Z')```. Additionally, since you wrote the file yourself, you could probably write it without including the index if you like.

Comment: I was just making an example, the data is in my dataframe, and so far as I understand, the default (series column) index is not part of range()

Comment: and I had even tried to use reset_index() to remove it, but reset_index() can only remove created indexes rather than a default numeric one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you didn't share your code.

I used this:

```
data = [['A',100],['B',200],['C',300],['D',230],['E',470],['F',168]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['item','sales'])

wb = xw.Book()  
wb = xw.Book(r'C:\Users\XXXXXXX\Documents\xport.xlsx') 
sht1 = wb.sheets['Hoja1']
sht1.range('A1').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = df
```

If I open the excel I find this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

If your data is csv data, you can use this code.

```
df = pd.read_csv(fileName_only, index_col='item')
```